# Crystal report SetDatasource issue

Tags: crystal-reports, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a Classic ASP page with VB6 code. We are in a process of converting the crystal report and iis server for migration. We are not able to generate the report. When i debugged till the point i call the "Database.SetDataSource CDOSet, 3,1" it works fine. When i comment that single line i'm able to get the report without any data. We are also using the .ttx file for database connection(Field Definitions Only). Kindly suggest me were could have been the mistake. What all things i need to check for the migrating?

*crystal report 9 to Crystal report 2008, iis 5 to iis 6

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suggest you look at is the Schema for the dataset and make sure it matches exactly with what the report is expecting.

Is it possible that while migrating some of the datatypes have changed and thats whats causing your problem now? if so it might be a simple fix to change the datatype in the report to match the new dataset

Comment: Actually it is not a dataset. We are using Crystal Data Object. This object is later set as the datasource for the Crystal report. Moreover migration is done by just changing the tool and not in the code. Since we migrated the source files to the new server i'm not able to get the report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with your setup, but my first guess would be a permissions issue. I would try looking at the event viewer on the server for more information, then the IIS logs.

Comment: Since the coding is in classic asp we wont get error logs in event viewer or IIS logs. I just have doubt whether it can be an issue in the crystal report .rpt file. whether it has been configured to different datasource. is there any way to check the same.

Comment: @Krishn - Classic ASP isn't your issue. Depending on the error IIS or Windows will still log it. Of course I am talking about on the server. For instance if your ASP page is running under the context of the anonymous user and a Crystal object cannot be created because of permissions that will probably be logged. Another trick is to write error handling into your ASP page (for debugging) and return the error and any helpful information in the response string to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Beaner.
But my problem is after the Database.SetDataSource CDOSet, 3,1 command the program is not going to the next line instead it hangs up in that line and after few mins internet explorer returns a Cannot display the web page error message. No logs in event viewer and IIS logs.